# Server redirect too many times(20) error when trying to get response code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, redirect

I am writing a program that will test that redirects that were setup are working by cheking the response code from the new URL.  I am running into an issue where half way thru running i get the following error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at Test.testredirects.AppTest.test(AppTest.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Is there a way to ignore this error or raise the number of redirects allowed?

Here is the main bit of code I am running:

```
public void test() throws Exception {



        String fails[] = new String[1000];
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System
                .getProperty("user.home")));
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        String file;
        File selectedFile = null;

        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Selected file: "
                    + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error",
                    "Please choose a file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        file = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

        int i = 0;

        while (dataRow != null) {

            String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
            for (String item : dataArray) {

                URL url = new URL(item);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();
                i++;
                int code = connection.getResponseCode();

                System.out.print(item + " " + code + "\n");

                if (code != 200) {
                    fails[i] = code + " " + item + "\n";
                }
            }

            // driver.get(item); // Print the data line.
            dataRow = CSVFile.readLine();

        }

        int a = 0;

        CSVFile.close();

        File resultsFile = new File("c://results.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(resultsFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        do {
            bw.write(fails[a]);
            a++;
        } while (a <= fails.length);

        bw.close();



}
```

Comment: Are you sure that increasing the number of allowed redirects is what you want to do? Sounds like you have a url in your app which redirects back to itself sending the client into an infinite loop

Comment: Bit of a hunch - you don't have a "redirect loop" happening? I.e. you request X from location A and are redirected to location B which redirects back to location A again?

Comment: No, the list I am using I have manually verified that there are no errors.  Some should 404 and the majority should return a 200

Answer (score 0):

This may help, in Servlets, even though you use :

```
response.redirect(URL);
```

or

```
requestDispatcher.forward(request,response)
```

succeeding code will still proceed after those calls, the fix is to use `return;` after those calls.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please help with how to use this?  I don't mean to seem daft,  I am a QA Analyst, not a developer.  Thanks.

Comment: show us the other codes used in this operation, we cannot give you answers unless you do that. Probably though, this method calls another method that ends up in this method, or in a same way, check your method calls and loops